# Cannot create an instance of a namedtuple subclass: TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, python-2.7, namedtuple

I seem to be unable to instantiate a `namedtuple` subclass:

```
from collections import namedtuple

foo = namedtuple("foo",["a","b","c"])
class Foo(foo):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(a=a,b=b,c=a+b)
```

When I try to create an instance, I get:

```
>>> Foo(1,2)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

I expected `Foo(1,2,3)`.

There seems to be a workaround: using a class method instead of `__init__`:

```
class Foo(foo):
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, a, b):
        return cls(a=a, b=b, c=a+b)
```

Now `Foo.get(1,2)` indeed returns `foo(a=1, b=2, c=3)`.

However, this looks ugly.

Is this the only way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Named tuples are *immutable*, you need to use the [`__new__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) instead:

```
class Foo(foo):
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, a=a, b=b, c=a+b)
```

(Note: `__new__` is implicitly made a static method, so you need to pass on the `cls` argument explicitly; the method returns the newly created instance).

`__init__` can't be used because that is called after the instance has already been created and so would not be able to mutate the tuple anymore.

Note that you should really add a `__slots__ = ()` line to your subclass; a named tuple has no `__dict__` dictionary cluttering up your memory, but your subclass *will* unless you add the `__slots__` line:

```
class Foo(foo):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, a=a, b=b, c=a+b)
```

That way you get to keep the memory footprint of your named tuples low. See the [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#slots) documentation:

> The action of a *`__slots__`* declaration is limited to the class where it is defined. As a result, subclasses will have a *`__dict__`* unless they also define *`__slots__`* (which must only contain names of any *additional* slots).

Comment: Actually, I did want to have `__dict__` but it is not there (2.7.14).

Comment: @sds: no, and that's by design. Subclass the namedtuple and leave out the `__slots__` line in the subclass if you really want one, but consider adding a slot for the attribute you want to add instead.

Comment: I did ***not*** add the `__slots__ = ()` you recommended, and I still do not have `__dict__`. Sorry about being unclear.

Comment: I get the same as you do - `f.__dict__` is `{}` instead of `{'a': 42, 'c': 123, 'b': 81}` as I expected.

Comment: moreover, when I add `__slots__ = foo._fields` in `Foo`, I get `TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    nonempty __slots__ not supported for subtype of 'foo'`

Comment: btw, thanks a lot for your kind help. please tell me if you prefer that I ask a separate question.

Comment: You can't make a namedtuple not use slots, no. Why do you want to do that? `namedtuples` are always immutable. Perhaps you wanted a dataclass instead, see [What are python data classes and how are they different from common classes?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47955263)

Comment: I see, thanks. I guess my confusion stems from your recommended `__slots__ = ()` making no observable difference. As for data classes -- yes, they look interesting and useful, but I am using 2.7, so this is not for me.

Comment: @sds: `__slots__` applies *per class*; a subclass shouldn't change what how a base class uses attributes. Slots are implemented with descriptor objects defined on the class, so a subclass would have to explicitly provide different descriptor objects to override them. Because a `__dict__` object is relatively costly in terms of memory, I always make sure I teach people about using `__slots__` on a subclass, as they would otherwise undo the benefits the base-class had. On Python 2, you can use the [`attrs` project](http://www.attrs.org/en/stable/) (the inspiration for dataclasses).